# WPF XBAP DPI scaling inside Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, wpf, scaling, dpi, xbap

I have a WPF application which can be run as an xbap application inside IE, and as a standalone WPF application.

When one of the monitors has scaling enabled, the standalone version works OK. With the XBAP version I keep having problems.

For example this scenario: Screen 1 has no scaling (100%), screen 2 has scaling (150%).

Starting the standalone version on screen 1 shows the UI like you would expect. Requesting the scaling factor in code returns 1. Moving the window to screen 2 scales everything up, as it should.

Starting the xbap version on screen 1 shows the UI zoomed in. It doesn't change when moved to screen 2. The IE window hosting the xbap is not scaled up on screen 1, so why is the xbap scaled up? When requesting the scaling factor in code, I receive 1.5.

This makes my application to be huge (zoomed in), even when started & displayed on a screen not using scaling.

Any ideas how I could fix this?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: Apparently this might help. Didn't test it myself though:

Add regkey @
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE:
DWORD (32-bit) with label ‘iexplore.exe’ and value ‘1’.

Source: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3165808/internet-explorer-11-window-display-changes-between-a-built-in-device

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Didn't quite fix it. It changes something but I am still getting the bottom and right 25% of the viewable area not used. I can deal with that, although the scrollbars keep disappearing until I resize the window. At this stage it looks like I need to drop to 100% zoom to get it to render nicely. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: Any solution identified to above case...? facing same issue with my xbap application.

Comment: Adding the regkey I mentioned above fixed it for me. But apparently, not for everyone/in all cases...